# support vector machine regression & prediction using MATLAB fitrsvm function

Tags: matlab, regression, svm, libsvm

I'm relatively new to using SVM and I have a question regarding how to use the results of the SVM regression. I have found many easy-to-understand documentation on SVM classification, and I can understand how to use the result of SVM for binary classification (i.e. data on one side of the support vector is labeled as one, data on the other side of the support vector is labeled as another), but I have no been able to find such hints on SVM regression- which is why I have run into the following question:

Using both libsvm package and the fitrsvm function in MATLAB, I was able to successfully generate models that are capable of fitting the abalone data set. the result of the libsvm (using svmtrain function) was used along with svmpredict to the successfully predict with new input parameters as followed:

```
model=svmtrain(age_train,X_train,['-s 3 -t 2 -c 2 -g 2']);
[prediction,accuracy,~]=svmpredict(age_eval,X_eval,model);
```

Also, as I've said, I was able to achieve the same results using the fitrsvm function as followed:

```
model1=fitrsvm(X_train,age_train,'OptimizeHyperparameters','auto',...
    'HyperparameterOptimizationOptions',struct('AcquisitionFunctionName',...
    'expected-improvement-plus'),'KernelFunction','rbf');
age_predict1=predict(model1,X_eval);
```

Now my question is, how do the svmpredict function (in the case of libsvm package) and the predict function (in the case of fitrsvm function in MATLAB) take the values within the trained models and apply them to the new input data? For example, is there a mathematical equation in which I apply the parameters of the trained model (such as the 'Mu' and the 'Sigma' parameters in the fitrsvm result) to the new input data to obtain the results?

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me with this or refer me to someone/somewhere who can help me, thank you very much in advance.